# Primefaces problem: p:filedownload from p:datatable with ViewScoped managed bean

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

p:filedownload from p:datatable with ViewScoped managed bean wont work. It calls the methods prepareFile and getFile twice. In first call of the methods I mentioned it sets the first file from the table, and in the second call of the methods it sets the right file, but it always downloads only the first one and the second one is never downloaded.

Why does it call twice? Why does it set the first file from the table? Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="offer_attachment_datatable"
                     widgetVar="offer_attachment_datatable"
                     var="attachment"
                     value="#{offerBean.offerAttachments}">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header"/>
                <p:commandLink ajax="false" actionListener="#{offerBean.prepareFile(attachment)}" title="#{attachment.name}">
                    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/themes/navigator_b2e/images/drive-download.png" />
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{offerBean.file}"/>
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

and in managed bean (simplified):

```
private StreamedContent file;
private InputStream stream;

public void prepareFile(OfferAttachment attachment){
    System.out.println("Attachment: "+attachment.getName());
    stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(attachment.getAttachment());
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/plain", attachment.getName());
    stream = null;
}

public StreamedContent getFile() {
    System.out.println("File: "+file.getName());
    return file;
}

public void setFile(StreamedContent file) {
    this.file = file;
}
```

So, I made a workaround with a simple p:confirmDialog where I extracted the problematic ajax=false command link, so I select the attachment by clicking it in p:datatable and execute the download from the p:confirmdialog.

Comment: I've also tried passing the rowIndex as a f:param, but it always sends  the same rowIndex: only the first one clicked on. I think problem might be around this ajax=false, but I'm not sure... I'm using PrimeFaces 2.2.1. and Glassfish 3.1

Comment: Now it seems like the bean is destroyed. It downloads the right file, but when I try some action after that, i get

`SEVERE: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean offerBean`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in 2.2.1. I found the solution by replacing `p:commandLink` to `p:commandButton` with the same attributes. Seems that it is a bug related with behavior of the `commandLink` component

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys, so I made a workaround with a simple p:confirmDialog where I extracted the problematic ajax=false command link, so I select the attachment by clicking it in p:datatable and execute the download from the p:confirmdialog.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to replace "p:datatable" with "ui:repeat(facelets) and table", like this:

```
<table role="grid">
<thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <ui:repeat value="#{downloadFileBean.files}" var="f">
        <tr role="row">
            <td><h:outputText value="#{f.name}" /></td>
            <td>
                <p:commandLink id="download" ajax="false">
                    <h:outputText value="Download" />
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadFileBean.file}" />
                    <f:param name="fileName" value="#{f.name}" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</tbody>
```