# ViewScoped bean destroyed when ajax=false

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, download, primefaces

This issue is connected with my previous question I've had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221750/primefaces-problem-pfiledownload-from-pdatatable-with-viewscoped-managed-bean).

So, I made a workaround with a simple p:confirmDialog where I extracted the problematic ajax=false command link, so I select the attachment by clicking it in p:datatable and execute the download from the p:confirmdialog.

Now it seems like the bean is destroyed. It downloads the right file, but when I try some action after that from the datatable (such as deleting a row), i get this:

`SEVERE: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean offerBean`